# How to upgrade virt-manager and all its dependencies without upgrading ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, virtualization, ppa

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 on the Jetson nano. I'm trying to virtualize FreeBSD 13.2 using virt-manager with all the dependencies that it brings,but I see that the version shipped with ubuntu 20.04 is obviously bugged and I would like to upgrade it. In this specific case,I see that there is a bug in libvirt that does not allow to boot FreeBSD 13.2 for arm64 / aarch64,that I've got from here :

https://download.freebsd.org/releases/arm64/aarch64/ISO-IMAGES/13.2/FreeBSD-13.2-RELEASE-arm64-aarch64-disc1.iso

These are the Hypervisor details :

> Hypervisor = KVM
>
> Architecture = aarch64
>
> Emulator = /usr/bin/qemu-system-aarch64
>
> Machine type = virt-4.2
>
> Firmware = UEFI aarch64 : /usr/share/AAVMF/AAVMF_CODE.fd

the error that I get is :

```
qemu-system-aarch64: 

initialization of device cfi.pflash01 failed.
 
device requires 67108864 bytes,block backend provides 67112960 bytes...
```

Point is that I can't upgrade Ubuntu 20.04 to a new release,because doing it I will lose the functionality of all the nVidia tools bundled with the official Jetson nano pack that are shipped with ubuntu 18.04. I've Been able to upgrade ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 following this tutorial :

https://qengineering.eu/install-ubuntu-20.04-on-jetson-nano.html

but I doubt that I will be able to perform another upgrade. So I would like to understand how can I upgrade ONLY the qemu + libvirt + virt-manager. I prefer for sure to install everything from deb files rather than compiling from sources,because doing this is much more complicated 'cause all the parameters have to pass to the compiler.

I forgot to say that the PPA below does not work on ubuntu 20.04 for arm (and for X64) :

```
Error:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/virtualization/ppa/ubuntu lunar Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
Found:21 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu focal-apps-updates InRelease
Found:22 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu focal-infra-security InRelease
Found:23 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu focal-infra-updates InRelease
Reading packages list... Done                                                                        
E: repository "http://ppa.launchpad.net/virtualization/ppa/ubuntu lunar Release" does not have a file Release.
N: the upgrade of this repository can't be executed securely and it is disabled as default.
```

Someone knows a recent virtualization PPA to share with me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecanonical-server/+archive/ubuntu/server-backports) that regularly and automatically Backports more recent virt stack packages. Using that you should be able to stay at 20.04